# Magento 2 Stuck on Checkout page

Tags: magento2, checkout, requirejs, static-content-deploy

I am using magento 2.2.3. And my issue is, on frontend I am getting below errors which stucks checkout page. Means, Page Loader is continuosly loading on checkout page so customer can not do anything :

[image]

Errors :::

> Error: Script error for: mageplaza/core/bootstrap
>   http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:166:17
>
> Error:
>   https://website.com/pub/static/version1552373356/frontend/Mytheme/theme-grocery/en_US/js-translation.json
>   HTTP status: 404

If I am trying to deploy static content then some errors are displaying on cmd :

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getPackage() on
>   null in
>   /home/mysite/public_html/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Package/Processor/PostProcessor/CssUrls.php:215
>   Stack trace:
>
> #0 /home/mysite/public_html/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Package/Processor/PostProcessor/CssUrls.php(109):
>   Magento\Deploy\Package\Processor\PostProcessor\CssUrls->getValidExternalUrl('{{base_url_path...',
>   Object(Magento\Deploy\Package\Package))
>
> #1 /home/mysite/public_html/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Package/Processor/PostProcessor/CssUrls.php(80):
>   Magento\Deploy\Package\Processor\PostProcessor\CssUrls->parseCss(Array,
>   'css/email.css', 'frontend/Ionwe/...', '@import url("{{...',
>   Object(Magento\Deploy\Package\Package))
>
> #2 /home/mysite/public_html/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Service/DeployPackage.php(151):
>   Magento\Deploy\Package\Processor\PostProcessor\CssUrls->process(Object(Magento\Deploy\Package\Package),
>   Array)
>
> #3 /home/mysite/public_html/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Service/DeployPackage.php(107):
>   Magento\Deploy\Servi in
>   /home/mysite/public_html/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Package/Processor/PostProcessor/CssUrls.php
>   on line 215

Anyone can help on this ??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. remove  var/cache/* pub/static/* generated/* (rm -rf var/cache/* pub/static/* generated/*)
2. compile your code again ( php bin/magenot setup:di:compile)
3. add right file and folder permission 
       for folders 755
       for files   644